# Extract icon from UWP application

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, uwp

While trying to implement "Open With" functionality I encountered a problem with extracting icons from UWP applications. So, after receiving list of recommended applications to open particular file with the help of [SHAssocEnumHandlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762109(v=vs.85).aspx), I'm trying to extract icons for each of these applications with the help of [IAssocHandler::GetIconLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776317(v=vs.85).aspx) and classical `ExtractIcon()`. Everything works ok with programs like Paint, for example. I have full path to Paint binary and can extract icon from it. But with applications like "3D builder", "Photos" and other UWP applications obtained icon location looks like `@{Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.511.8630.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.Photos/Files/Assets/PhotosAppList.png}`. I tried couple of different APIs to extract icon and each time received FILE_NOT_FOUND error. So, can anyone give me a hint which function can be used to extract icon in that case?

**UPDATE**
Some parts of source code added to clarify the situation:

```
// m_handlers is a member of type std::vector<CComPtr<IAssocHandler>>

HRESULT FileManager::GetAssocHandlers(const std::wstring& strFileExtension, ASSOC_FILTER filter)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<IEnumAssocHandlers> enumerator;

    m_handlers.clear();

    hr = SHAssocEnumHandlers(strFileExtension.c_str(), filter, &enumerator);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        for (CComPtr<IAssocHandler> handler;
            enumerator->Next(1, &handler, nullptr) == S_OK;
            handler.Release())
        {
            m_handlers.push_back(handler);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT FileManager::GetAssociatedPrograms(BSTR bstrFileName, BSTR* bstrRet)
{
    ...
    hr = GetAssocHandlers(strFileExtension, ASSOC_FILTER_RECOMMENDED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ...
        for (auto& handler : m_handlers)
        {
            ...
            if (SUCCEEDED(handler->GetIconLocation(&tmpStr, &resourceIndex)))
            {
                // And this is where I get classic full file path to regular
                // applications like "MS Paint" or this weird path mentioned
                // above for "Photos" UWP application for example which can't
                // be used in regular ExtractIcon functions.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I was pretty sure that the standard `ExtractAssociatedIcon` API function worked just fine. Exported from shell32.dll. It's unclear where you are obtaining this path to a PNG file. What do you mean when you say "obtained icon location looks like?" Obtained from where? `ExtractIcon` and `ExtractAssociatedIcon` return HICONs, not strings or paths. Posting the code you're trying would be a good start.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for your comment. Added some code to clarify the situation. What I'm trying to do is to get the list of recommended applications to open *.jpg file, for example. After I get the list of recommended applications I want to show them in "Open With" context menu with their icons on the left (pretty much the same as Windows Explorer works). So, when recommended application is UWP application,  IAssocHandler::GetIconLocation for this recommended app returns me this odd path to PNG file. Hope, it's clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I've found the solution. The icon location path provided for UWP application is called "indirect string" according to MSDN. We can pass this indirect string to [SHLoadIndirectString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759919(v=vs.85).aspx) function and will receive the regular full path to the icon PNG file. In my case after passing `@{Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.511.8630.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.Photos/Files/Assets/PhotosAppList.png}` to SHLoadIndirectString() I received path like that: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.511.8630.0_neutral_split.scale-125_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets\PhotosAppList.scale-125.png` and after that I can use it to display the icon itself w/o any problem.

Comment: Thank you. SHLoadIndirectString function helped me to retrive icon for windows store application.