# How can I extract the icons within an exe or dll file?

Tags: uwp

In Windows Desktop there is a function named ExtractAssociatedIcon but for uwp i found nothing about this function. I would choose an exe or dll file via FileOpenPicker ad extract all icons inside of it.
It's possible in UWP?

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you can call [LoadPackagedLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh447159.aspx) on arbitrary files. But if all else fails, you can load the file and manually parse the resource directory, and extract the icons you wish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract icon from UWP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417757/extract-icon-from-uwp-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's possible in UWP?

AFAIK, there is no such API for UWP app now, but it doesn't mean it is not possible in UWP. If your app will not be published into store, there is a method to use Win32 API in UWP app.

You can refer to [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can follow the steps in the document [VS2015TemplateBrokeredComponents](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/10be07b3-67ef-4e02-9243-01b78cd27935) to build a bridge between UWP app and traditional desktop app.